# What does "timestamp" of "header" in hokuyo's scan data?

Tags: ros, laser, hokuyo-node, hokuyo, timestamp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm wondering what timestamp in hokuyo's sensor_msgs::LaserScan does mean. Is the time at first scan ray is measured? Or is the time at last scan ray is measured?

I know there is calibration function of latency between hokuyo and host PC in hokuyo node. But I cannot understand how the function works. Could you explain to me?
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223911/what-does-%22timestamp%22-of-%22header%22-in-hokuyo%27s-scan-data?/) by [claid00](https://answers.ros.org/users/25547/claid00/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-01-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The timestamp is the the time of the first ray/distance measurement in a scan. Note this is also stated in the comments of the [sensors_msgs/LaserScan](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html) message definition.

The time calibration performs some sending of messages back and forth between scanner and host similar to [NTP time synchronization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol#Clock_synchronization_algorithm). There is some more info [here on page 27 of the UTM-30LX-EW protocol documentation](https://www.hokuyo-aut.jp/02sensor/07scanner/download/pdf/UTM-30LX-EW_protocol_en.pdf).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [claid00](https://answers.ros.org/users/25547/claid00/) on 2016-01-12**:
Thank you ~~
May I ask one more? As far, the timestamp is the first ray measurement in a scan. Is the timestamp based on host PC timer by time calibration? There are two timer, in hokuyo and in host PC.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2016-01-12**:
Yes, the driver node should take care of publishing the proper ROS timestamp for the message, based on the preceding time calibration. For details you have to look at the code.

**Comment by [claid00](https://answers.ros.org/users/25547/claid00/) on 2016-01-12**:
Thank you~
The timestamp of encoder data from rosaria is also based on host PC. In rosaria code, the timestamp of encoder is updated by ros::Time.now () just before publishing. Am I right?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2016-01-12**:
Don't know, you'll have to look at the code. But just taking ros::Time::now() is an approach that's commonly taken if no complicated sync as with the hokuyo is done.

**Comment by [claid00](https://answers.ros.org/users/25547/claid00/) on 2016-01-12**:
Thank you~ I'll have to look at the code. Thanks~